# Create a ZIP Archive without compression?

Tags: php, zip

Is there a way to add JPG Files to a ZIP Archive without recompressing them? Sounds weird I know.

Creating a ZIP File via PHP uses lots of CPU. Using ZIP with no comprssion still uses lots of CPU. If I only want to add Images (JPG) to the Archive, why should they be recompressed when the JPGs are already compressed?

I know that every file in a ZIP Archive needs to be in a different Format (compressed) than the original File, but maybe there is a way to only set some headers in front of every file (without recompression) and copy those together to a ZIP Archive.

Comment: Does it have to be zip? Because [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format))s are ideal for archiving without compression... There is a PHP implementation in [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar)

Comment: JPEG images are conpressed a second time by the ZIP file, however it is a different kind of compression, no data is lost.

Also, I agree with @DaveRandom, tarballs are a good idea here.

Comment: Thanks. I will checkout a tarball.

Comment: At last, PHP7 has the apropriate functions to do this, setCompressionName() & setCompressionIndex().

Comment: @Mike did you try with tarball? Is it using less CPU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have tagged this `php`, I'll assume that your question applies to the PHP zip extension, in which case the answer is:

No there isn't.

The PHP zip extension [does not currently allow you to set the compression method](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41243&edit=3). (The bug has been open for several years and was still unresolved as of Jan 2012).

Comment: As of 2017, all is good now! just use $zip->setCompressionIndex($ix, ZipArchive::CM_STORE);

Comment: @user247245 Note that it's only available in PHP 7.

Comment: how do I set the compression level using `addGlob()`?

Comment: @Mirko — There is an "Ask Question" link in the top right of every stackoverflow page you can use if you have a new question.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, I think after being a member for 8 years I should have noticed that ;)

Answer (score 3):

ZipArchive doesn't allow this (as far as I'm aware, although the extension isn't fully documented in the php.net manual).

However, the [PCLZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip) library does allow a PCLZIP_OPT_NO_COMPRESSION argument when adding a file to a zip.